# Shortcode inside shortcode not working in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, shortcode

I need to add shortcodes such as `image`, `hr` and `button`. However, I also needed to remove the `wpautop` filter (`remove_filter('the_content','wpautop')`) for hr to work properly. Now, to manually set paraghraps I set a shortcode `p`to simply convert `[p]text[/p]` with `<p>text</p>`.

But, inside `[p /]` the other shortcodes aren't working. I guess that it modifies the content. Here's my simple function:

```
function p_func($atts,$content) {
    return '<p>'.$content.'</p>';
}
add_shortcode('p','p_func');
```

I'm getting a bit nervous with this, as my `functions.php` seems to be full of hacks already. Any advice?

Martti Laine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you need to remove `wpautop` for your `hr` shortcode as it gets wrapped in a paragraph?

If so, just use your shortcode like so;

```
Some text in my editor.

[hr]

A bit more text.
```

See the line break spacing? WordPress will automatically ensure that shortcode 'by itself' won't get wrapped in paragraphs.

I'd strongly advise going down the route you are at the moment - if what I've mentioned above isn't the problem, what *is*? Let's look at tackling it rather than re-inventing the wheel!

For the record, if you need to apply nested shortcode, from [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Output);

> If the enclosing shortcode is intended
>   to permit other shortcodes in its
>   output, the handler function can call
>   do_shortcode() recursively:
>
> ```
> function caption_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
>    return '<span class="caption">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</span>';
> }
> ```